# why /socket.io/socket.io.js is not found in npm 1.4.9?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, localhost, npm

I am doing chat application and i am using npm 1.4.9 version but i have one small problem every time i am starting the node.js server only one error message is coming.

**GET /socket.io/socket.io.js 500** and after that nothing is happening.

**My Code**

```
//index.html

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
</script>
```

Please kindly suggest me some solution.

Comment: what does your server code look like?

Comment: You must post your server code. That's where the error is. It needs to send the socketio browser code in response to GET /socket.io/socket.io.js but it's crashing instead.